# No me funciona link de descarga

Tags: html5, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes colegas.

Estoy trayendo los datos de tablas de la BD y lo muestro en una tabla HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
$signo = "$";
if ($quote->num_rows > 0){
    $item = $since+1;
    while ($rowQuote = $quote->fetch_assoc()){
        $numberQuote = $rowQuote['QUOTE_NUMBER'];
        $client = $rowQuote['CLIENTE_NOMBRE'];
        $subtotal = $rowQuote['QAMOUNT_SUBTOTAL'];
        $tax = $rowQuote['QAMOUNT_TAXVALUE'];
        $total = $rowQuote['QAMOUNT_TOTAL'];    
        $fcreation = $rowQuote['QUOTE_CREATED_DATE'];
        $date = date_create($fcreation);
        $fecha=date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
        $fexpe = $rowQuote['QUOTE_EXPIRE_DATE'];
        $state = $rowQuote['QUOTE_STATUS'];
        $url = "billing/quotes/".$numberQuote.".pdf";
        $usercreator = $rowQuote['QUOTE_USUARIOID'];
        $Name = $rowQuote['USUARIO_NOMBRES'];
        $lastName = $rowQuote['USUARIO_APELLIDOS'];
        $names = ucwords($Name." ".$lastName);;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$item.'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$numberQuote.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$client.'</td>';
        echo '<td align="right">'.$signo.number_format($subtotal,2,'.',',').'</td>';
        echo '<td align="right">'.$signo.number_format($tax,2,'.',',').'</td>';
        echo '<td align="right">'.$signo.number_format($total,2,'.',',').'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$fecha.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$fexpe.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$names.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$states.'</td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center;"><a download href="'.$url.'" class="pdfs hint--left-middle hint--rounded" aria-label="Download pdf"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>';
        echo '<td align="center"><a href="?numbers='.$numberQuote.'" class="number_quote hint--left hint--rounded" aria-label="Check in"><strong><i class="icon-check-square-o"></i></strong></a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $item++;
    }
}else
    echo '<tr><td colspan="10" align="center"><strong>No records found</strong></td></tr>';
```

Hasta ahí, todo funciona bien; en el penúltimo TD estoy colocando un link de descargar, en el cual se descargara un archivo PDF alojado en el servidor:

```
'<td style="text-align: center;"><a download href="'.$url.'" class="view_pdf hint--left-middle hint--rounded" aria-label="Download pdf"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>';
```

Pero al darle click, no me hace la descarga. Confirme la ruta y esta bien. Lo cambie a

```
 $numberQs = $numberQuote.".pdf";
 <a download href="billing/quotes/'.$numberQs.'" class="view_pdf hint--bottom hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Download pdf"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="copy_quote hint--bottom hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Copy and generate new quote"><i class="icon-copy"></i></a>
```

Pero sigue sin funcionarme. De antemano, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda prestada.

**EDITO**

Estuve revisando, coloque el puntero del mouse sobre el link para que me muestre la ruta y esta correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿en `$url` esta la ruta local o la url a donde se accede? ¿podrías dar un ejemplo del valor que tiene `$url`, verificando que esté en el servidor?

Comment: Si colega.. lo asigno acá:$url = "billing/quotes/".$numberQuote.".pdf";

Comment: y el valor de `$numberQuote`? Me refiero al valor final de la URL que se ve en el navegador... existe esa URL? es el lugar donde está el archivo? En caso de que no, cuál sería la correcta?

Comment: ¿Por qué no estás poniendo el prefijo (`http://` o `https://`)? Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43803778/5587982), debes poner al menos `//` delante o el cliente no sabrá a donde ir resultando en una ruta inválida. Por claridad y estandarización, conviene que pongas siempre el prefijo y el nombre del dominio.

Comment: Si, la ruta existe:                                                                                                                           $numberQuote = $rowQuote['QUOTE_NUMBER'];                                                                    
 $url = "billing/quotes/".$numberQuote.".pdf";                                                                                       
 echo '<td style="text-align: center;"><a download href="'.$url.'" class="pdfs hint--left-middle hint--rounded" aria-label="Download pdf"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>';

Comment: Bien. Y si a ruta es la correcta, y el archivo está ahí y el navegador accede... entonces, *cuál es el problema*? Acaso estás preguntando por qué tu navegador abre el PDF en vez de descargarlo?

Comment: El problema es que al dar click en el link no hace nada. No descarga el archivo

Comment: Lo que estás mostrando de código yo lo veo bien... ¿Habrá algún evento desde JavaScript que esté interceptando el click?